# Existing open source software for wireless mesh networking?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

My goal:

- Build a wireless mesh network with some ALIX 2D2 (500 MHz AMD Geode LX800 x86 CPU, 256MB RAM, Atheros wireless card)
- Aside from working like a normal wireless mesh network users should be able to read/write data from/to the ALIX Boxes and the ALIX boxes should be able to process data.

Questions:

- Should I try to flash dd-wrt x86, voyage linux (linux.voyage.hk) or something else?
- What (open source) software should I look into before I start?
- Should I use a 'server' for data storage and processing instead of the ALIX boxes? Is it even possible to use the ALIX boxes for routing AND data storage and processing?

Final notes:

- Data can be anything, for example, I want to setup a wireless mesh using the OLSRD protocol so my whole town gets wifi and can access songs on the network. It's not for that, but that's the idea.
- I'm not afraid of programing, compiling or working with *nix. This is mostly 'for fun' rather than for practicality.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I found a company [Meraki](http://meraki.com/lp/free-eval?src=gd&cid=cmbranch&gclid=CNn0vtnzrKwCFQaFQAodzmZeGw) that is commercializing the [open source MIT roofnet technology](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/roofnet/doku.php).

It uses a mesh routing technology, and is a true wireless mesh network technology, apparently widely deployed in university, and other large campus environments.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a protocol that recently made it into the linux kernel to do this called [BATMAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.A.T.M.A.N.). I've never tried it but theoretically should be available in some of the newer distros already.

Answer (score 0):

check out hostapd.  you would use this software if you wanted to (for example) turn a linux box into a wireless AP.  hostapd supports mesh networks as well.